# Does the variable have to be on the left always?

Tags: linear-algebra

When I was in class I had to solve the equation $60 = \frac{200}{r^3}$ and find the value of $r$. I tried to solve it by first multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{200}$ leading to $\frac{60}{200}=r^3$, then $0.3=r^3$ then $r = \sqrt[3]{0.3}$

but that was wrong instead you were to multiply by $r^3$ first. Why is that right but my way isn't?

Comment: Simple answer : no. But it's more convenient since you read from left to right. However if you multiply by $\frac{1}{200}$ you still have $\frac{1}{r^3}$ on the right not $r^3$ so what you wrote is wrong.

Comment: After multiplying by $1/200$ you get $60/200=1/r^3$.

Comment: Generally, when the variable $r$ is not already on the left in the question, you will have to put it on the left somewhere (anywhere) in your computation, in order to end up with the solution(s) written as $r=\dots.$

Answer (score 1):

You did the steps wrongly at "... then $0.3 = r^3$ ..."

It does not matter whether the variable is on the left or on the right. It is just a convention to have the variable on the left so that it is easier to read.

Observe how I do it with both cases where the variables on the left / on the right:

1. Variable on the left

$60 = \frac{200}{r^3}$ 
$60r^3 = 200$ *(Multiply $r^3$ on both sides)* 
$r^3 = \frac{200}{60}= \frac{10}{3}$ *(Divide $60$ on both sides and simplify $\frac {200}{3}\space to\space \frac{10}{3}$)*
$r = \sqrt[3]{\frac{10}{3}} = 1.49 \space(3sf)$ *(Cube root both sides)*

2. Variable on the right

$60 = \frac{200}{r^3}$ 
$\frac{60}{200} = \frac{1}{r^3}$ *(This is the part where you get confused. Notice that it is like so because if you bring $200$ over to the right side, we are essentially doing this: $$60 \cdot \frac{1}{200}= \frac{200}{r^3} \cdot \frac{1}{200}$$ 
Which will give you: $$\frac{60}{200}=\frac{1}{r^3}$$

If we take the reciprocal on both sides, we will get: $$\frac{200}{60}=r^3$$

which will give you the same answer. Observe that it is less confusing when the variable is on the left, so I suggest that you follow the convention! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you i realized my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply both sides by $1/200$ you get
$$
\frac{60}{200}=\frac{1}{r^3}\tag{1}
$$
Think to
$$
4=\frac{8}{2}
$$
which is a true equality; if you multiply both sides by $1/8$, you get
$$
\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
which is still true, not
$$
\frac{4}{8}=2
$$
which is clearly false.

Now our ($1$) becomes
$$
\frac{10}{3}=r^3
$$
by taking reciprocals and this ends up in
$$
r=\sqrt[3]{10/3}
$$

Comment: Thank you i realized my mistake